# List view by query foreign key django

Tags: django

I an application which you can create project and each project is going to have some reports,
In my main page it shows the users projects which includes ( Reference, Project Type, Project Name and Date), and you can create report and in report there is a foreign key which you can choose to point to specific project,
I want when user click on reference of project, application shows the list of reports that is related to that project

This is my
[Models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgcHw.png)

Comment: Please paste code, instead of posting images of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.